# De excel a Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js

Como puedo leer e importar datos de un excel a un json/array?

Estoy creando un catálogo donde quiero hacer cargas masivas.

Comment: Podrías describir mejor con algún ejemplo que intentas realizar?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es poner el código que tienes hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor :)

Comment: Gracias por comentar, miren tengo un catalogo de articulos, lo que quiero implementar es subir la informacion en excel, para, de este modo subir varios articulos de un solo golpe, y no tener que irse de articulo en articulo.

Comment: entonces, ocupo convertir la informacion que tengo en el excel a JSON, para mandarlo a la api, y se guarde en la bd.

Answer (score 0):

quizas te sirve esto: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx
Entiendo que querés importarlo a vueJS, fijate en la lista de frameworks que ahí aparece.

Comment: Gracias por comentar compañero, ya lo he solucionado con Jquery (me encontre en una pagina las indicaciones y el codigo, y funciono a la perfección... por ahora)